# is there a way to return booleans for finding whether a node is connected as well as its components?

Tags: python

So this is for understanding, and I am trying to code a way to identify where there is a connection, sort of a like a society of nodes. Basically, if I input a matrix and a node, it will return True or False if the given node has components that are already related.

I have tried using a while loop to loop through visited sets, but I am still lost in the process. I feel more comfortable with for loops, in terms of understanding. If there is a way to iterate a list of submatrices to find relations between nodes that would be easy to understand and adapt.

```
def society(graph_matrix, node):

    for item in (graph_matrix):
        for j in item:
            if graph_matrix[item][j] and graph_matrix[item][node] and graph_matrix[j][node] == 1:
                return True
    return False


gmatrix =  [ [0,1,1,1,0],
             [1,0,0,1,0],
             [1,0,0,0,1],
             [1,1,0,0,0],
             [0,0,1,0,0] ]
```

so if I input `(society(gmatrix,0))` the answer should return `True`, as when you look at node 0 you can see its connection to node 1 and node 3, and node 1 is connected to node 3 as can be observed in the gmatrix matrix. sorta like a society of nodes. I am

however, `society(gmatrix,2)` should return `False`, node 2 is connected to 0, and 4 but 0 and 4 are not connected.

Comment: How do you find connections between each node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `for item in (graph_matrix):`,  here `item` represents a list of numbers.
And you can not use list of numbers as the matrix indices like this: `graph_matrix[item][node]`.

As far as i understood your problem, you want to know if three nodes are interconnected or not. To do this you can modify your code in the following way:

```
def society(graph_matrix, node):
    for i in range(len(graph_matrix[node])):
        for j in range(len(graph_matrix[node])):
            if graph_matrix[node][i] and graph_matrix[node][j] and graph_matrix[i][j] == 1:
                return True
    return False


gmatrix =  [ [0,1,1,1,0],
             [1,0,0,1,0],
             [1,0,0,0,1],
             [1,1,0,0,0],
             [0,0,1,0,0] ]

print(society(gmatrix, 0));
```

Here, `len(graph_matrix[node])` will return the **length** of `graph_matrix[node]` and `range(len(graph_matrix[node]))` will iterate from **0** to **length-1**.

Answer (score 1):

I think that having your graph in matrix form makes this harder to think about than it needs to be. Converting the edge connection lists so that they are instead lists of connected nodes would make things easier (and, as a bonus, reduce the computational load in the event that `society()` would return `False`, more important as the number of nodes increase):

```python
def to_map(gmatrix):
    return [[k for k,v in enumerate(edges) if v] for edges in gmatrix]
```

Then you'd be able to do:

```python
def society(graph_map, node):
    for n in graph_map[node]:
        if n == node:
            continue
        for nn in graph_map[n]:
            if nn != node and nn != n and nn in graph_map[node]:
               return True
    return False
```

As in:

```python
gmatrix =  [ [0,1,1,1,0],
             [1,0,0,1,0],
             [1,0,0,0,1],
             [1,1,0,0,0],
             [0,0,1,0,0] ]
gmap = to_map(gmatrix)

print(society(gmap,0)) # True
print(society(gmap,2)) # False
```